# Jq: how to address a random-like key in json

Tags: jq

in AWS CLI, the command **aws quicksight describe-data-set blah blah** returns a json document with the following troublesome syntax:

```
{
    "Status": 200,
    "DataSet": {
        "Arn": "arn:aws:quicksight:<region>:<acct>:dataset/b7c87122-e180-47a9-a8a4-19f171e13fc8",
        "DataSetId": "b7c87122-e180-47a9-a8a4-19f171e13fc8",
        "Name": "MyName",
        "CreatedTime": "2022-08-16T12:01:54.948000-05:00",
        "LastUpdatedTime": "2022-08-19T08:47:55.553000-05:00",
        "PhysicalTableMap": {
            "6fac5dee-3691-4ddd-ba7a-0667168bb80c": {
                "CustomSql": {
                    "DataSourceArn": "arn:aws:quicksight:<region>:<acct>:datasource/46f83f8b-181e-4575-8d61-84c50125f3aa",
```

I need to address that DataSetArn, but the key "6fac5dee-3691-4ddd-ba7a-0667168bb80c" is unknown to me at runtime.  How do I address it?

I tried:

```
jq -r '.DataSet.PhysicalTableMap.*.CustomSql.DataSourceArn'
jq -r '.DataSet.PhysicalTableMap.\*.CustomSql.DataSourceArn'

jq -r '.DataSet.PhysicalTableMap.?.CustomSql.DataSourceArn'
jq -r '.DataSet.PhysicalTableMap.\?.CustomSql.DataSourceArn'

jq -r '.DataSet.PhysicalTableMap.%.CustomSql.DataSourceArn'
jq -r '.DataSet.PhysicalTableMap.\%.CustomSql.DataSourceArn'
```

All return an error similar to:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.DataSet.PhysicalTableMap.\?.CustomSql.DataSourceArn
jq: 1 compile error
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I'm a noob, I know I'm guessing here.  Does anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
jq -r '.DataSet.PhysicalTableMap[].CustomSql.DataSourceArn'
```

The part `.DataSet.PhysicalTableMap` returns the object as *one* result, the following filter `[]` takes that object and returns *each* value as *one* result. The following filters take each of these separate results and refines more stuff.

Note: If the object is the top-level item then the syntax is `.[]` .

Comment: I don't understand why this works, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: Explained a bit...